# How do I force uppercase field entries in Gravity Forms to submit as lowercase?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

This form, using Gravity Forms, is an artist application for a juried event, and we request their website and social media URLs. If there are any capitalized letters in the entry, Zapier cannot process these fields when processing them into Zoho CRM. The URL entries must all be lowercase. Using CSS to force lowercase didn't solve this, as the field entry would still be uppercase in the database. So now I'm trying to use functions. However, the code below is not working. Thank you for any help you can provide with this!

```
add_filter( 'gform_save_field_value_8_54', 'lowercase_text', 10, 3 );
function lowercase_text( $value, $entry, $field ) {
if ( $field->get_input_type() == 'text' ) {
    $value = strtolower( $value );
}

return $value;
}

add_filter( 'gform_save_field_value_8_55', 'lowercase_text_fb', 10, 3 );
function lowercase_text_fb( $value, $entry, $field ) {
if ( $field->get_input_type() == 'text' ) {
    $value = strtolower( $value );
}

return $value;
}

add_filter( 'gform_save_field_value_8_67', 'lowercase_text_insta', 10, 3 );
function lowercase_text_insta( $value, $entry, $field ) {
if ( $field->get_input_type() == 'text' ) {
    $value = strtolower( $value );
}

return $value;
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing multiple different functions that do _exactly_ the same thing, instead of specifying _one_ callback function in multiple places? _"However, the code below is not working."_ - what have you done to try and debug this then, so far? Have you at least verified whether these callback functions get executed at all?

Comment: The whole request does not make the most sense to begin with though, IMHO. While letter casing might not matter in domain names, it is a different thing for URL path & query string parameters. If I give you my website URL as `http://example.com/FOOBAR`, then that must not necessarily mean, that `http://example.com/foobar` will show the same content. Much more likely, that it would get a 404. _"Zapier cannot process these fields when processing them into Zoho CRM."_ - then someone needs to tell either of these systems to stop _messing up_ in that regard ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello thank you for question,

Try below hook it will work

```
add_action("gform_pre_submission_8", "pre_submission_handler");
function pre_submission_handler($form)
{
   $_POST["input_54"] = strtolower($_POST['input_54']);
   $_POST["input_55"] = strtolower($_POST['input_55']);
   $_POST["input_67"] = strtolower($_POST['input_67']);
}
```

Comment: To clarify, I tried the first part of the code, for lowercase_text, to apply to a single field. The others didn't work either when used alone or alongside the first. When I tried combining them, it didn't work either.

I agree that this is an issue with Zapier and Zoho CRM, but that is less fixable than solving this on my end.

maheshmthorat, the code you provided works perfectly! THANK YOU!!! I appreciate you so very much!!